# Make Windows Install all Updates on a Certain Day

Tags: windows, windows-update, automatic-updates

I would like our servers to install all available updates every Saturday. I set the "Configure Automatic Updates" group policy. I then configured it to "Auto download and schedule the install." Then, I set the installation date for Saturday at 3 a.m. However, last Saturday only a first set of updates were installed. Now, when I check the servers, it says there are more updates available. So, I guess the server will install the next set of updates this upcoming Saturday.

When I manually update certain servers, I have to check for Windows updates multiple times and install them multiple times with multiple reboots in order to get the server fully up to date. I would like Windows to do all of that in one day. I don't want to have to wait multiple weeks to finish installing the latest Windows updates on the servers. When I check the update history, it shows some have failed, but if it updates enough times, the errors go away. We are using WSUS.

Comment: The Windows Update "cycle" runs just once per "instantiation". You can't make it run more than once or make it run until all available updates are installed. What you can do (which may be as close as you can get to your desired state) is to configure updates installation every day.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to install all updates in one go, that too automatically without any intervention! The updates require a restart/reboot for an effective installation of pending for reboot & installation kind of updates.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a third-party application called ABC Update. Using the Windows Task Scheduler, I can schedule ABC Update to run several times every Saturday to install all the updates.

Comment: you can do the same using PowerShell Windows Update cmdlets and Task Scheduler.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a computer expert. Update message received often leads to "Not to install" because it refers to restart quite often hampering current work. If a particular date is fixed for the update, the customer can schedule and be prepared for it. "Ones a Month scheduling policy" would be most welcome for regular, pro, and occasional computer users. The monthly cases could be any one from 1st-5th, or 25th-Last day; all software & web companies should agree with.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/529475)